# How to use onchange, onmouseup event in codemirror text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, codemirror

I am using my text editor as codemirror. Normally when I try to use dom event like `onmouseup, onchange, oninput` in textarea it works, but after integrating the codemirror, it is not working. Please tell me the correct way to invoke these events in my text editor.

Without codemirror, it works.

```
<textarea id="editor" rows="30" cols="100" onchange="myFunction()" onmouseup="second();"></textarea>        
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="second"></div> 
<script>
  function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="The onchange function..";}    
  function second() {
       document.getElementById('second').innerHTML="The mouseup function..";}
</script>
```

On integrating codemirror text editor, it is not working. Here is a code:

```
<textarea id="editor" onchange="myFunction()" onmouseup="second();"></textarea>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="second"></div> 
<script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea
    (document.getElementById('editor'),{
            mode:"text/x-java",
            lineNumbers:true,
            autoCloseTags:true,
            tabSize:5       
    });
    editor.setSize("1000", "450");              
    </script>       
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="The onchange function..";}         
    function second() {
         document.getElementById('second').innerHTML="The mouseup function..";}

    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because those events are not actually taking place on the textarea since it is hidden, rather, you will need to bind the events to the `.CodeMirror` element like so:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '.CodeMirror', function() {
    // do something...
});
$(document).on('change', '.CodeMirror', function() {
    // do something...
});
```

Also, I use `keyup` rather than a `change` event because you have to click out of the `.CodeMirror` to make the change function run...

Answer (score -1):

CoreMirror has a method `fromTextArea` that takes two parameters - first the source and second is the property that would like the editor to look like.

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea
   (document.getElementById('editor'),{
       mode:"text/x-java",
       lineNumbers:true,
       autoCloseTags:true,
       tabSize:5       
    });
```

Once the output from above `fromTextArea` is taken into a variable, it provides the method `on` that again takes two params. First is the type of event that you would like to perform which in this case is the 'change' event and second is the operation that you would like to perform, which in this case simply consoling the output:

```
editor.on('change', // change it your event
  (args) => {
  console.log("changes");
  console.log(args);
})
```